# Attribute "data-name" is not allowed here

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio, svg

I am working in Android Studio and have +100 errors in my different svg files.

[image: image-link]

Android Studio suggests to remove all of the "data-name" attributes. I have tried to "sync project with gradle files" but it does not solve my problem.

How should I solve this issue without removing the attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio includes a tool called Vector Asset Studio that helps you add material icons and import Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) and Adobe Photoshop Document (PSD) files into your project as vector drawable resources. Using vector drawables instead of bitmaps reduces the size of your APK because the same file can be resized for different screen densities without loss of image quality.

For importing an SVG file as vector asset you should do following steps :

1. Open Resource Manager Tab
   [image]
2. Click On Plus Icon And Select Vector Assets
   [image]
3. Check Local File And Choose A Name For Your Vector (Without .svg Suffix) And Path to .svg File
   [image]
4. FINISH!